# Pass a php variable through a javascript redirect html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, pass-by-reference

I am making a SQL table viewing page through PHP, and I am trying to create popup windows through links in the table.
I have a php variable $formID
I am making a popup window by echoing a javascript script, like

```
echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>'<script type=\'text/javascript\'>window.open(\'awards.php?formID\',\'Window1\',
\'menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no\');</script>'</td>";
```

would that pass $formID to awards.PHP or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: is there a missing ( after window.open?

Comment: and `‘` & `’` will give you syntax errors.

Comment: @sachleen I copypasted this code from a tutorial and I'm trying to make it fit my needs, fixed that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awards.php?formID` this will not the pass form id since php does not recognize it as a variable and replace with its value . Use the `awards.php?form_id={$formID}`

you recieve the variable like `$getformID = $_GET['form_id'];`

Comment: and from awards.php do i recieve the variable like $formID = $_GET['formID'];
?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;"><script type="text/javascript">window.open(\'awards.php?formID='.urlencode($formID).'\', \'Window1\', \'menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no\');</script></td>';
```

From awards.php you can get it like this:

```
$formID = urldecode($_GET['formID']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><script type='text/javascript'>window.open('awards.php?formID={$formID}','Window1','menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no');</script></td>";
```

That will probably work. Then on your other page, get the value with `$_GET['formID']`.

You don't need to escape the single quotes because they're all in a set of double quotes. You only need to do that if you're nesting quotes of the same kind.

You could also do something like this:

```
"part of your string " . $formID . " rest of my string";
```

or

```
"part of your string {$formID} rest of my string."
```

More info on this [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: It's possible to embed PHP variables inside a string directly, like: *"part of your string $formID rest of my string"*. The curly braces syntax is handy if you want to embed a variable that is an element of an array or a member of an object, i.e: *"part of your string {$this->formId} rest of my string"*